# Where is web.xml in Eclipse Dynamic Web Project

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse I clicked File->New->Dynamic Web Project
and I am following a tutorial for Jersey that now wants me to go and change something in web.xml file...but I can't even find this file.
What is it I am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 91, accepted):

When you create a Dynamic Web Project you have the option to automatically create the web.xml file.
If you don't mark that, the eclipse doesn't create it...

So, you have to add a new web.xml file in the WEB-INF folder.

To add a web.xml click on `Next` -> `Next` instead of `Finish`. You will find it on the final screen of the wizard.

Comment: I think you can right-click the project and select "Java EE Tools" -> "Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub". It made me a web.xml

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer for those who forgot to check the option.

Answer (score 52):

you can do it by **Dynamic Web Project –> RightClick –> Java EE Tools –> Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub.**

Answer (score 31):

**If you don't see the web.xml file in WEB-INF folder,**

[image]

**- Select Deployment Descriptor and right click on it.

 - Then select the Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub**

[image]

**Finally you get web.xml file.**

[image]

Answer (score 10):

When you open Eclipse you should click **File** → **New** → **Dynamic Web Project**, and make sure you checked **Generate `web.xml`**, as described above.

If you have already created the project, you should go to the `WebContent/WEB-INF` folder, open `web.xml`, and put the following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Application Name </display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 9):

Might be your project is not JEE nature, to do this **Right Click -> Properties -> Project Facets and click Convert to facet and check dynamic web module and ok**. Now you will be able to see Java EE Tools.

Answer (score 6):

Follow below steps to generate web.xml in Eclipse with existing Dynamic Web Project

1. Right Click on Created Dynamic Web Project
2. Mouse Over Java EE Tools
3. Click on Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub
4. Now you are able to see web.xml file on WEB-INF folder

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The web.xml file should be listed right below the last line in your screenshot and resides in `WebContent/WEB-INF`. If it is missing you might have missed to check the "Generate web.xml deployment descriptor" option on the third page of the Dynamic web project wizard.

Answer (score 3):

If you missed to check the "generate web.xml" option when creating a new project, no worries 
If it is a Dynamic Web Project in your project right click on "Deployment Descriptor:...." and Click on
"Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub" this will create a minimal /webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml.

Comment: how to  edit web.xml because eclipse generates 404 when i run project  web-inf resource not found

Answer (score 1):

For gradle / maven project you can use src/main/webapp/WEB-INF folder by default:

```
- main
- - java
- - resources
- - webapp
- - - META-INF
- - - - context.xml
- - - WEB-INF
- - - - web.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

If your deployment descriptor tab is disabled, then click on update libraries it will also do your work. It will create. Xml file in Web content

Comment: I was facing this issue. Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub option was disabled. On updating library, an web.xml file was created.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating a project in the wrong way,I am going to post here in step by step

Step 1: File>>New>>Project>>Web>>Dynamic Web Project

Step 2: Enter Project Name>>Next>>Next>>

Step 3: **Check the checkbox for Generate web.xml deployment descriptor**

Step 4: Finish

Please follow this way you will get you web.xml file under WEB-INF folder

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: right-click on the project and select `Java EE Tools` -> `Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub`. web.xml should be generated.